# Python: How can i read the environment variables / user path variables from another user?

Tags: windows, python, windows-registry, environment-variables

As far as i know, the user variables (of the currently logged on user) are stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`. User path variables are stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders` and the system variables are stored in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`. [Thanks to this source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/573818/940592)

I am trying to read the environment variable `%APPDATA%` of all existing users. My python `script` is getting `executed` with `system rights`.

It is possible to read environment variables using `os.environ()`. But i did not find any documentation, which environment variables are read (the current logged on user variables or the system variables).

So is it possible to read the `user path variables` of all existing users?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registry key/value you need is:

```
Key: HKEY_USERS\[SID]\Volatile Environment\
Value: AppData
```

So you would need to iterate through all of the currently loaded hives in HKEY_USERS for each SID.